# How did the events of the flashback concerning how Reginald Hargreeves' came into possession of what would be Vanya's Violin change history?

Tags: the-umbrella-academy

In one of the final episodes of *The Umbrella Academy* we find that Vanya's violin is not something that was purchased explicitly for her.

> The violin belonged to Reginald Hargreeves' wife, or at least a woman who he cared for very much. She appears to be terminally ill, and she wishes that it would go to someone who enjoys playing it as much as she did.

Also in this scene we see and hear,

> Explosions in the distance and we see out the window that several missiles, presumably ICBM's or similar are launching. Conventional wisdom and histories with similar tropes state that if we see multiple ICBMs launching then the world is in the process of ending, one of the nuclear powers is launching a first or retaliatory strike and a mad-max future is imminent.

That is obviously not the case though from the given story. We know this flashback to have actually occurred given that Reginald has the violin he received during the flashback, but none of the other incidents from the flashback seem to have an effect on the history of the show -- Given their magnitude it's hard to believe they wouldn't be mentioned.

**How did the events of the flashback concerning how Reginald Hargreeves' came into possession of what would be Vanya's Violin change history?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The events of the flashback do not affect the history of the world because as in the comics,

> Reginald Hargreeves is a space alien. The [TvTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ComicBook/TheUmbrellaAcademy) article for the comic has this in a spoiler tag in the introduction.

The events in the flashback are not ICBMs launching

> They are spaceships leaving. Reginald is being told to get on one.

Comment: A human-looking one I assume? That was also very human-looking in architecture, technology (violins, umbrellas). Even Krypton looks more alien.